# When give html cellspacing equal to 0 table starts from next page while printing

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a report I've successfully repeated header and footer in every page at my desire location but the problem arose with a table which has 37 data rows. when I give cellspacing HTML attribute to this table than while printing it starts from the next page I don't know why any suggestions  ? ? ? 
Here is my **[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fscjaw92/42/)**

```
       <table cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: Which of the 8 tables in the fiddle are we talking about?

Comment: @MrLister we are talking about the table who has 37 rows having sr,description,total and soo on

Comment: I'm stuck at that point because when i give cellspacing 0 to that table it starts from the next page while printting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank's for your contribution! Please try to edit your question to include the essential parts of the code. Here you can read about general guidelines for good questions: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!